# Special shape of Line starting and ending point in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Hello I need a solution of special shape of starting and ending line. I use Line Property . I want a solution like this .[image].

You can see there is "+" shape of this Line property in starting and ending . How to do in XAML and in my code . Here is my code

```
<Canvas Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableCanvas}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=ISCanvasVisible, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
<Image Source="{Binding DIIMGFINAL}"    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MDownCalCulateDistance($source, $eventArgs)];
[Event MouseUp] = [Action MUpCalCulateDistance($source, $eventArgs)];
[Event MouseMove] = [Action MMoveCalCulateDistance($source, $eventArgs)]" Stretch="Uniform" />
<Line Visibility="{Binding Path=ISLineDistanceVisible, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"  IsHitTestVisible="False"  X1="{Binding FirstPoint.X}" Y1="{Binding FirstPoint.Y}"
X2="{Binding SecondPoint.X}" Y2="{Binding SecondPoint.Y}" StrokeStartLineCap="Triangle"  StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" 
Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2">

</Line>
<TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding TxtblckPoint_First_Left.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding TxtblckPoint_Second_Left.Y}" Text="{Binding Path=DisTanceInMM, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock></Canvas>
```

As you can see I use StrokeStartLineCap and StrokeEndLineCap Triangle but it is not what I wanted . It can  visible if I use StrokeThickness a greater value . But my requirement is not that much thick . Here is My C# code

```
                     if (_firstPoint.X == 0 && _firstPoint.Y == 0)
                    {
                    System.Windows.Point px1 = e.GetPosition((System.Windows.Controls.Image)sender);

                    _firstPoint = px1;
                    }
                    else if((_firstPoint.X != 0 && _firstPoint.Y != 0) && (_secondPoint.X == 0 && _secondPoint.Y == 0)){
                    System.Windows.Point px2 = e.GetPosition((System.Windows.Controls.Image)sender);
                    _secondPoint = px2;
                    var geometry = new FrameGeometry(DicomDataSet);
                    var patientCoord1 = geometry.TransformImagePointToPatient(new Point2(Convert.ToInt32(_firstPoint.X), Convert.ToInt32(_firstPoint.Y)));
                    var patientCoord2 = geometry.TransformImagePointToPatient(new Point2(Convert.ToInt32(_secondPoint.X), Convert.ToInt32(_secondPoint.Y)));

                    FirstPoint = _firstPoint;
                    SecondPoint = _secondPoint;}
```

What I have to do to show the special shape of Starting and Ending Point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place two Path elements with whatever shape you need at the endpoints.

Comment: Can you give some code I could not Understand

Comment: Where Should I place in C# or XAML

Answer (score 2):

Place two Path elements with whatever shape you need at the endpoints:

```
<Path Stroke="Red" Data="M-5,0 L5,0 M0,-5 L0,5"
      Canvas.Left="{Binding FirstPoint.X}"
      Canvas.Top="{Binding FirstPoint.Y}"/>

<Path Stroke="Red"
      Canvas.Left="{Binding SecondPoint.X}"
      Canvas.Top="{Binding SecondPoint.Y}">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="-5,0" EndPoint="5,0"/>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,-5" EndPoint="0,5"/>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Thanks . It can create the shape but Line is not working now I'm working on that

Comment: Thanks it works but I have faced another Issue Have to solve it now